# DataGrid in WPF 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How do I add a Column to a DataGrid in WPF?

Comment: Programmatically? Using Xaml?  At runtime, or at design time?  You need to ask a more precise question, I suspect.

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is, but to avoid downvotes please clarify and expand the question. provide code if any or provide a background for the question.

Comment: I tried to edit it, but I didn't want to add details that were incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about programatically, you can do this:

```
DataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn());
```

Or XAML

```
<DataGrid Height="148" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,21,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" />
```

You will probably be best served by checking out a [tutorial on WPF DataGrids](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html).

Also, here's a tutorial on how to

[Add Controls to a DataGrid at Runtime](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tameta/AddingControlstoaDataGridatRuntime11262005041201AM/AddingControlstoaDataGridatRuntime.aspx)